# Can you provide links to FDA definition of organic that work?

Tags: discussion

None of your links to FDA definition of organic work.

For example:

1. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/42503/1672
2. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/42544/1672

Comment: organic == made from carbon.

Comment: I suspect that you're talking about some dead links in older answers, but I have no idea which ones...

Comment: Can you show where you've seen these links? It's better for us to fix them than for you to ask a new question. If you [edit] your question and include the links to the questions you're talking about, we'll try to fix the links.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and migrate this to meta (the site for discussing things that are on the actual site). If you can point us at any dead links we'll be happy to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can fix these things by using [archive.org](https://archive.org/) to find the original document, then using Google to search for some snippet of text from it and find a still-working copy. Failing that you can always link straight to the archive.org copy.

Also, despite what that answer said, it's actually the USDA that publishes organic labeling requirements, not the FDA.

1. Fixed.
2. Fixed. (Dunno if it's the most useful link, but it's the new version of the site for the same program.)